# Remove URL Input field Validations but accept only URL without https

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-input

I want to accept a `URL` in my input field. But i don't care about `https://` or `https://`. I just want to remove this validation. But it should only accept a `URL`.

Example like this `www.example.com` or `example.com` should be acceptable.

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="form-box d-flex justify-content-between" enctype="multipart/form-data">                            
    <input type="url" class="form-control" name="url">
    <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn">Find</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Use the html input `pattern` attribute, and match `.`. That should be all required for a web address. And no special chars. See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: @gilbert-v Thank you for giving Hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i made the answer for my question. I am using Regular Expression for validation.

```
<input                      
pattern="^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$" 
placeholder="Find your website ranking... Eg - site.com" class="form-control" name="url"
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Enter URL.')"
onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"
>
```

URL Cheker Regex - `^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$`

I am using bellow javascript to change the message of validation -

```
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Enter URL.')"
onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"
```

Comment: Possibly worth noting for future folks that this solution requires removing the type="url" attribute because browsers automatically apply a check for a protocol (http(s)) in addition to whatever pattern you set on that input type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url#Validation

As a result, you won't get whatever custom keyboard a given mobile device would supply for the url input type.